# WSO2 - Identity Server 6.1.0 - Sign in with google

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I enabled the sign in with google on the identity server 6.1.0 as described in the documentation. When i sign in from my web application, once the google consent page is displayed and i should be redirected to my main app, i get an error saying that the gmail is not a valid tenant:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} - Exception in Authentication Framework org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityRuntimeException: Invalid tenant domain gmail.com
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityRuntimeException.error(IdentityRuntimeException.java:55)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityTenantUtil.getTenantId(IdentityTenantUtil.java:274)
```

am i supposed to change anything in the front end app? or is something missing on IS level?

What i did as configuration is:

- creating identity provider with google secret keys
- enable it on service provider level

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the email contain `+` character ?

Comment: no it doesnt. Just "."

Comment: Did you enable the JIT provisioning ?

Comment: How can i do it? do you have any hints or link? or its under wso2 docs?

Comment: Can you share the configurations in the service provider? Need to see how login options are configured. Seems to be like the server is considering gmail.com as the tenant.

Comment: I added some screenshots under the description. Thank you so much for your help